# How do you pass outputs of two different models as inputs to a another model in keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

[Here's the kind of model I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zLJn.jpg)

I'm trying to make a sort of adversarial network. I have already trained a discriminator. Now I want to connect outputs of two separate VGG16 models to this discriminator. I'm trying to avoid retraining the discriminator and just simply load pre-trained weights, that is why I want to load the model and then somehow connect it with the two VGG16 models.

If there is a way I can load the weights for the discriminator part only somehow that would be great as well!

Apologies if my query is not in line with the guidelines, this is my second every post on stackoverflow.

EDIT: Here's the code I've written for the overall structure without loading weights, i.e. I will be training this from scratch.

sat/street extractors are VGG16 networks that learn features

```
    sat_fv = sat_extractor.layers[-1].output
    str_fv = street_extractor.layers[-1].output

    deep_sat_feat = Reshape((32, 32, 1))(sat_fv)
    deep_street_feat = Reshape((32, 32, 1))(str_fv)
    deep_merged = concatenate([deep_sat_feat, deep_street_feat], axis=3)

    deep_act_1 = conv2d_block(deep_merged)

    flat = Flatten()(deep_act_1)
    dense = Dense(4096)(flat)
    act = LeakyReLU()(dense)
    dense = Dense(1024)(act)
    act = LeakyReLU()(dense)
    dense = Dense(128)(act)
    act = LeakyReLU()(dense)

    den_3 = Dense(1)(act)
    act_5 = Activation("sigmoid")(den_3)

    generator_model = Model(inputs=[sat_extractor.input,street_extractor.input], outputs=[sat_fv,str_fv,act_5])
    discriminator_model = Model(inputs=[sat_extractor.input,street_extractor.input], outputs=[act_5])
    generator_model.compile('Adam',loss=['categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy','binary_crossentropy'],loss_weights=[1/15,1/15,1/3])
    discriminator_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(0.00001), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Comment: How do you want to combine the parameters? Simply concatenate them?

Comment: I haven't thought about it so I'm sure. What would be the recommended approach?

Comment: Hey @UmairKhawaja, it would be helpful to provide us with what you have done already.

Comment: @valkon I have added it to the post

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is, that I have a trained discriminator, and I just want to attach it infront of the two VGG16 models, by passing the output of these models as input to the discriminator